# Power BI Custom Matrix Design

Tags: matrix, reporting-services, powerbi, report, dashboard

i have a table i need to design where rows are the actual values as below 
[image]

i tried to use table, the results were as below, which is not what i want:

[image]

i tried to use a matrix , i couldnt reach the desired design as well:

[image]

can any one have any idea how to do such thing?

Comment: you'll need to transform the data in your data model. There are options to transpose and unpivot in the query editor. Unpivot the brokerage, commision and other columns  into a new column (called measure for example). You will then be able to use that column in a matrix to get the desired results

Comment: i think the unpivot will solve my problem, however i cant do it in the current table since i have other visualization attached to this table, also i have many measures created in this table using DAX which they are not visible in edit query and i cannot unpivot them; can you advise what to do next in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it using same concept adopted in the below solution
[Custom aggregate column in power bi matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52632713/custom-aggregate-column-in-power-bi-matrix)

best regards,
Georges