# Custom matrix header

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need to create a custom header like the picture below:

[image]

I check this link [Custom aggregate column in power bi matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52632713/custom-aggregate-column-in-power-bi-matrix/52635791) 
But I don't undestand how to do the same to my case?

**Edit**

I try to create calculated table but I didn't get the data for dim5 and dim6, how can I modify it?

[image]

**Edit**

Dim_prduit

[image]

My problem is how to dispaly Nombre product , and then like hierarchy dim5 then dim6 in the header?

Comment: "I don't understand" is not a question. What is your specific question?

Comment: How to create the header described in powerbi?

Comment: You create a new calculated table defining the structure you need.

Comment: @AlexisOlson I update my question

Comment: It seems like you're on the right track. Can you share a sample `Dim_Produit` table so we can attempt to reproduce?

Comment: @AlexisOlson I update my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's ugly but you can write a header table like this and then define a switching measure based on the appropriate indices:

```
Header = 
ADDCOLUMNS (
    UNION (
        DATATABLE (
            "Top", STRING,
            "Index1", INTEGER,
            "Middle", STRING,
            "Index2", INTEGER,
            "Bottom", STRING,
            "Index3", INTEGER,
            {
                { "Nombre product", 1, "", 0, "", 0 },
                { "Affaires nouvelles", 2, "Total", 8, "", 0 },
                { "Affaires nouvelles", 2, "%Total", 9, "", 0 }
            }
        ),
        SELECTCOLUMNS (
            SUMMARIZECOLUMNS ( Dim_Prod[dim5], Dim_Prod[dim6] ),
            "Top", "Affaires nouvelles",
            "Index1", 2,
            "Middle", Dim_Prod[dim5],
            "Index2", RANK.EQ ( Dim_Prod[dim5], Dim_Prod[dim5], ASC ),
            "Bottom", Dim_Prod[dim6],
            "Index3", RANK.EQ ( Dim_Prod[dim6], Dim_Prod[dim6] )
        )
    ),
    "Index0", 100 * [Index1] + 10 * [Index2] + [Index3]
)
```

Output:

[image: Output]

---

Sample measure:

```
SampleMeasure =
VAR Top = SELECTEDVALUE ( Header[Top] )
VAR Middle = SELECTEDVALUE ( Header[Middle] )
VAR BottomIndex = SELECTEDVALUE ( Header[Index3] )
RETURN
    SWITCH (
        TRUE (),
        Top = "Nombre product", [NombreProductMeasure],
        Top = "Affaires nouvelles" && BottomIndex <> 0, [DimensionMeasure],
        Middle = "Total", [TotalMeasure],
        Middle = "%Total", [%TotalMeasure]
    )
```

This is pretty hacky though. Power BI may not be the best tool here.

Comment: A `SWITCH` to define what calculation to use in what situation.

Comment: In the matrix, I will put in the column part, top then middle then bottom?

Comment: Yep. 3 levels in that order. You'll have to drill down to expand the columns.

Comment: For the measure calculation, can you put an example? I'm not sure that I understand it's quiet difficult.

Comment: I've added an example.

Comment: Could you please help me to figure out how to use DimensionMeasure correctly? I put an example in the following question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61543224/wrong-values-with-customized-double-header-in-matrix . If you have any idea that you can help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Power BI is not a pixel-perfect data visualization tool, therefore, it is not possible to create customer headers using Built-in visualizations.

Therefore you have pretty much two options:

1. Build your own [custom visualization](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/developers/custom-visualization/), using Javascript, Python or R
2. Use a pixel-perfect tool like [SSRS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/create-deploy-and-manage-mobile-and-paginated-reports?view=sql-server-ver15)