# multiple results- the query fails

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to link between header table and the fact table in order to get correct values:

```
Formules = 
VAR Top1 = SELECTEDVALUE ( EnteteRapportAgentClient[Top] )
VAR Middle = SELECTEDVALUE ( EnteteRapportAgentClient[Middle] )
VAR BottomIndex = SELECTEDVALUE ( EnteteRapportAgentClient[Index3] )
VAR a = SELECTEDVALUE ( Dim_DateFicheAgent[ID_DateFicheAgent] )
VAR b = SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Seniority banking'[banking seniority] )
VAR Bottom = SELECTEDVALUE ( EnteteRapportAgentClient[Bottom] )
VAR Val =
    SWITCH (
        TRUE (),
        Top1 = "Nombre de leads", [Lead] + 0,
        Top1 = "Affaires nouvelles"
            && BottomIndex <> 0, CALCULATE (
            COUNTROWS (
                FILTER (
                    Fact_AN,
                    (
                        Fact_AN[banking seniority] <= b
                            && NOT ISBLANK ( Fact_AN[banking seniority] )
                            && Fact_AN[Code_Produit ]
                                = LOOKUPVALUE (
                                    Dim_Produit[Code_Produit ],
                                    Dim_Produit[Dim5Rapport], Middle,
                                    Dim_Produit[Dim6Rapport], Bottom
                                )
                    )
                )
            ),
            DATESBETWEEN (
                Dim_DateFicheAgent[ID_DateFicheAgent],
                NEXTDAY (
                    SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR (
                        LASTDATE ( Dim_DateFicheAgent[ID_DateFicheAgent] )
                    )
                ),
                LASTDATE ( Dim_DateFicheAgent[ID_DateFicheAgent] )
            )
        ),
        Middle = "Affaires nouvelles", [AN] + 0,
        Middle = "Total AN", [AN] + 0,
        Middle = "Taux Transfo", DIVIDE ( [AN], [Lead] )
    )
VAR ValF = IF ( Middle = "Taux Transfo", FORMAT ( Val, "0.0%" ), FORMAT ( Val, "0" ) )
VAR Val2 = IF ( ValF = "0", "", ValF )
RETURN
    Val2
```

I get an error 
[image]

I put here a pbix file. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OwE52NRyq_W13u2N84pnNVw1lnatmOSw/view?usp=drivesdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot going on there but that particular error likely comes from `LOOKUPVALUE` not returning a unique value.

Comment: How could I replace LOOKUPVALUE please?

Comment: Well, how do you want to handle that case where the values aren't unique?

Comment: I am just trying to resolve the following questionhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/61543224/wrong-values-with-customized-double-header-in-matrix so if you can propose any solution it would be greatly appreciated!