# Change rows for matrix using radio buttons (DAX) in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

How or if is it possible to change rows for matrix using radio buttons (DAX). In this image it would be Category. It is possible to calculate sums based on filters provided by calculated metrics. I can't figure out how to change rows with DAX and am starting to think that PowerBI does not allow to do that, but expects you to create different reports. This would be really great way to reduce the pages in PowerBi.
[image: powerbi matrix]

Comment: what do you mean by - "how to change rows with DAX"?

Comment: You can create checkboxes using custom "columns/dax calculations" and slicer, but I only found a way to change calculated sums with that method. Would like to change rows (Category in this image) with radio buttons. I am just wondering if/how is it possible? I am not good with words, hope it's more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, Power BI doesn't currently have a simple way to achieve exactly what I think you are asking.

There are some hacky workarounds I can think of to approximate what you're suggesting but they're a lot of work and I'm not going to provide an answer along those lines. You might get some ideas as to what might be involved by examining [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52632713).

I think a better option is to use [bookmarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-bookmarks). Create a copy of the visual for each different set of row headers you want to see and use the bookmarks to control which one is visible (i.e. one bookmark for each version where that bookmark displays the respective version and hides all of the others).