# DAX / PowerBi - Listing values from multiple columns under single header column

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Okay, so I'm fairly new to DAX and not 100% sure this can be achieved. I have a table like below...
Current Output :
[image: Current Output]

And I am wanting to merge the 'Latest Weeks and yr ago' into groups such as 'Last 4,'Last 12' etc., this should make the table more readable.
I tried grouping, but each value can only be in one group, and some would need to be in mulitple groups - (ie 'latest 01-04...' would be in all groups). The table above changes dynamically based on a slicer.

What I am trying to achieve is something like this....
What I'm aiming for :
[image: What I'm aiming for]

Like I say, not sure it is possible, but hoping someone might have an idea.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is possible but a bit clunky.

One method is to set up a new parameter table to use for your column headers and define your measures to read that context and adjust accordingly. See [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52632713) for an example of how this works.

Another, perhaps simpler, method would be to use [calculation groups](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/introducing-calculation-groups/) where `Latest X Weeks` are your calculation items with formulas along the lines of

```
---
--- Calculation Item: Latest 12 weeks
---
CALCULATE ( 
    SELECTEDMEASURE (),
    DATESTBETWEEN ( DimDate[Date], TODAY() - 12 * 7, TODAY () )
)
```

Note: You can't create calculation groups in Power BI Dekstop (yet), so you'll need an external tool like Tabular Editor. This is explained in the previous link.