# Change the column name of a matrix depending on a filter selection

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the following matrix (I simplified it) :

[image]

I want when I select the months for the 2020 year, the name of the column Year becomes Year 2020
so that column is dynamically modified depending on the year selection.

and the next column will be Year N-1 which is Year 2019.
How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking here is whether it is possible for dax to dynamically change the measure name based on the slicer selection?

The answer is no. In the current capacity, it is not possible to dynamically change the measure name. MeasureName `MeasureName=sum(fact[sales])` is defined by the user.

Comment: The measure name can't change but you could create an independent Year parameter table to use on the matrix columns along with appropriate measures similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52632713/custom-aggregate-column-in-power-bi-matrix/52635791#52635791).